# 301 apache redirect non existing path using .htaccess joomla

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I want to redirect a path: /folder/filename.html to: /folder/newfolder.
My host says I must create a dummy file at /folder/filename.html or it won't redirect. I can't do this as by creating the /folder, that messes up Joomla which would normally create that part of the path dynamically. I'm not sure I believe my host, surely it's possible to redirect a path regardless whether there is a file there?

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess after `RewriteEngine On` just add this line

```
RewriteRule ^/folder/filename.html /folder/newfolder/filename.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That just results in a 404. I'm wondering if there could be something odd about the way this apache server is set up.